# Slider - adding title on a video in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html, slider

does anyone know how to add a title on a slider when 1 slide is a video format?

I have something like this:

```
  <!-- Swiper-->
  <div data-height="100vh" data-min-height="480px" data-slide-effect="fade" class="swiper-container swiper-slider">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper text-center">
      <div data-slide-bg="" class="swiper-slide">
        <video class="video-relative">
          <div id="overlay" class="swiper-slide-caption">
            <div class="shell">
              <h1>ProPlast</h1>
              <h6>Proffesional models</h6>
              <div class="button-group"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">More</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Contact</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <source src="images/foka.mov" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
      <div data-slide-bg="images/slajd1.jpg" class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-caption">
          <div class="shell">
            <h1>Proplast</h1>
            <h6>We create with passion</h6>
            <div class="button-group"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">More</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Contact</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Swiper Pagination-->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
```

The title does not appear on the video...

Comment: Did you try something before ? Could you please drop some css lines or any tried solution?

Comment: Are you serious about having that `div` inside the `video` element? If `video` is supported, then the contents, except for the `source` element, will be ignored.

Comment: @Manngo thank for the comment, then would you know how to add title without the div content inside?

Comment: @dutchsociety here is the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aorpzswy/1/

Comment: Well when you dont have that div inside the video element you could do it with css by using a before {content: "title"} and style it like you want, its not that beautifull way but it is working.

Comment: @dutchsociety thanks, I will try that!

Comment: Well Using :before or :after on a <video> tag won't work. ..

Comment: @dutchsociety I don’t think you can have `:before` or `:after` on `video` because it’s a replaced element, not a container.

Comment: @asheri You could try your luck putting the `video` inside the `div`. With the right CSS, you can create the effect you want.

Comment: @asheri not on the video element but you could give it a try on .swiper-slide with a child selector. Also the divs inside the video tag isn't valid. You should put the video element inside the div.

Comment: @Manngo thanks a lot, your advice had given me an idea how t search here http://www.imi21.com/background-video/ I found what to do and it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned above in the comments you would something like below.

```css
.swiper-slide {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

#overlay {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
  <!-- Swiper-->
  <div data-height="100vh" data-min-height="480px" data-slide-effect="fade" class="swiper-container swiper-slider">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper text-center">
      <div data-slide-bg="" class="swiper-slide">
        <video class="video-relative">
          <source src="images/foka.mov" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
          
        <div id="overlay" class="swiper-slide-caption">
          <div class="shell">
            <h1>ProPlast</h1>
            <h6>Proffesional models</h6>
            <div class="button-group">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">More</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Contact</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          
        
      </div>
      <div data-slide-bg="images/slajd1.jpg" class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-slide-caption">
          <div class="shell">
            <h1>Proplast</h1>
            <h6>We create with passion</h6>
            <div class="button-group"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">More</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Contact</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Swiper Pagination-->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
```

Please let me know if this works for you, if not I would do some changes for you!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!